# Import specific module for 'os._exit'

Tags: python, import, module

```
import os
os.exit(0)
```

Instead of importing the whole module, is there any way to import the specific module in OS? (This could make my program more efficient when used.)

Comment: do you mean `from  os import _exit`? I don't think that is  going to make much difference to your efficiency

Comment: Wouldn't it improve performance as it might take a few seconds more than usual?

Comment: If import os or os.exit(0) takes a few seconds you have some serious issues elsewhere, on my machine `import os -> 539 ns`

Comment: In the program I intend to use it in it takes 3.2sec (school computer)

Comment: By the way, my school is pretty bad when it comes to IT we run python 3.3.2 so I have to is "os.exit(0)" as an alternative to "raise SystemExit"

Comment: well `from os import _exit as exit` will do what you want but I will be amazed if it is the cause of your problem

Comment: I'll test and let you know and how to a measure the speed of how long it takes to Import a module.

Answer (score -1):

```
from os import _exit
```

This code should Import it specifically which should improve 'performance'.

Comment: This is literally a copy of a comment I made,   the performance difference will also be in the nanoseconds and almost certainly not going to have any impact on the OPs code taking 3.2sec to run .

Comment: This doesn't work mate, is their any other solution.

Comment: Bob, if you try the following from the shell: `$ python -c "from os import _exit ; exit(254)" ; echo $?` do you get `254` as output?